# Porting pointer functions to c#

Tags: c#

I have the following in C

```
typedef void (*procfunc)(V2fT2f *, float);

typedef struct {
    procfunc func;
    procfunc degen;
} Filter;

const Filter filter[] = {
    { brightness             },
    { contrast               },
    { extrapolate, greyscale },
    { hue                    },
    { extrapolate, blur      }, // The blur could be exaggerated by downsampling to half size
};
```

which I have brought over to C# to give me this

```
public delegate void procfunc(ImagingDefs.V2fT2f[] quad,float t);

    public class Filter
    {
        public procfunc func;
        public procfunc degen;
    };

    public Filter[] filter = new Filter[]
    {
        new Filter { func = brightness },
        new Filter { func = contrast },
        new Filter { func = extrapolate, degen = greyscale },
        new Filter { func = hue },
        new Filter { func = extrapolate, degen = blur } // The blur could be exaggerated by downsampling to half size
    };
```

My issue is that I'm getting the error

```
A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method or property.
```

I have a feeling that the issue is with the delegate, but I'm not sure - I've never needed to port this sort of code before.

Neither ImagingDefs nor V2fT2f are declared as static

The methods being called are typically

```
public void foo(ImagingDefs.V2fT2f[]quad, float t)
```

with nothing anywhere being static.

The name V2fT2f comes from the original source code

Comment: Like the error states, who is static and who is not? Show 1 or more of those methods too.

Comment: public void brightness(ImagingDefs.V2fT2f[]quad, float t) // t = 0 to 2 - nothing anywhere is declared as static

Comment: `V2fT2f` is not a particularly descriptive type name.  I'd highly suggest using a more meaningful name.

Comment: Don't add clarifcations as comments, edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method or property.* is referring to the filter methods such as `brightness`.

These methods must be made static if they're going to be referenced in your field initializer `filter`.

Another option is to initialize this field in the constructor of the class you're defining.

E.g.

```
public class MyNewClass
{
    public delegate void procfunc(ImagingDefs.V2fT2f[] quad,float t);

    public class Filter
    {
        public procfunc func;
        public procfunc degen;
    };

    public Filter[] filter;

    public MyNewClass()
    {
        filter = new Filter[]
        {
            new Filter { func = brightness },
            new Filter { func = contrast },
            new Filter { func = extrapolate, degen = greyscale },
            new Filter { func = hue },
            new Filter { func = extrapolate, degen = blur } // The blur could be exaggerated by downsampling to half size
        };
    }   
}
```